# How to test a Class.forName call in Java code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, classloader

I've been messing around with ClassLoaders in java recently, trying to test code which uses dynamic loading of classes (using `Class.forName(String name)`) with a custom `ClassLoader`.

I've got my own custom `ClassLoader` set up, which is supposed to be configurable to throw a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to load a given class.

```
public class CustomTestClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private static String[] notAllowed = new String[]{};
    public static void setNotAllowed(String... nonAllowedClassNames) {
        notAllowed = nonAllowedClassNames;
    }
    public static String[] getNotAllowed() {
        return notAllowed;
    }
    public CustomTestClassLoader(ClassLoader parent){super(parent);}
    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        for (String s : notAllowed) {
            if (name.equals(s)) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException("Loading this class is not allowed for testing purposes.");
            }
        }

        if(name.startsWith("java") || name.startsWith("sun") || getClass().getName().equals(name)) {
            return getParent().loadClass(name);
        }

        Class<?> gotOne = super.findLoadedClass(name);
        if (gotOne != null) {
            return gotOne;
        }

        Class<?> c;
        InputStream in = getParent().getResourceAsStream(name.replace('.', '/')+".class");
        if (in == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Couldn't locate the classfile: "+name);
        }
        try {
            byte[] classData = readBytes(in);
            c = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Couldn't read the class data.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {/* not much we can do at this point */}
        }

        if (resolve) {
            resolveClass(c);
        }
        return c;
    }

    private byte[] readBytes(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4194304];
        int read = in.read(buffer);
        while (read != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            read = in.read(buffer);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

I'm using `-Djava.system.class.loader=com.classloadertest.test.CustomTestClassLoader` to set this `classloader` as default `ClassLoader`.
I was hoping to be able to force a `ClassNotFoundException` by disallowing certain class names using `CustomTestClassLoader.setNotAllowed(String...)`.
However, it only works for `ClassLoader.loadClass`, and not for `Class.forName`:

```
public void test() {
    ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    CustomTestClassLoader custom = (CustomTestClassLoader)loader; 
    CustomTestClassLoader.setNotAllowed(NAME);
    for (String s : custom.getNotAllowed())
        System.out.println("notAllowed: "+s);
    try {
        System.out.println(Class.forName(NAME));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("forName(String) failed");
    }
    try {
        System.out.println(Class.forName(NAME,false,custom));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("forName(String,boolean,ClassLoader) failed");
    }
    try {
        System.out.println(custom.loadClass(NAME));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ClassLoader.loadClass failed");
    }
}
```

Now I expected all three try blocks to fail, since the documentation of `Class.forName` says it uses the `ClassLoader` of the caller (which should be custom/loader in this test).
However, only the final try block fails. Here is the output I get:

```
notAllowed: com.classloadertest.test.Test
class com.classloadertest.test.Test
class com.classloadertest.test.Test
ClassLoader.loadClass failed
```

Does `Class.forName` really use the `classloader`? And if so, which methods?
It seems to be using a native call, so I have no idea what it does under the covers.

Of course if anyone knows any alternative ways of testing a `Class.forName()` call, it would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: For openjdk you can have a look here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Class.java#Class.forName%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Your class isn't loaded before you add it to notAllowed ?

Comment: Following up on @JEY, if you set NAME = MyClass.toString(), you are loading the class; internal classes also behave weird.

Comment: NAME is indeed set to Test.class.getCanonicalName().
I figured a call to Class.forName would still invoke a load on the ClassLoader. So if it doesn't, it probably uses a native lookup, basically bypassing the ClassLoader? I tried debugging it, but I can't step through the native forName0 method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class.forName()` uses the classloader of the class where it is called from (e.g in your case the class that contains the `test()` method). So, if you are running it in a different environment this will cause the problem.

**UPDATE** That ClassLoader will be used in `Class.forName()` which loaded your `Test` class.  And that may be the solution:  It may be an Eclipse-defined classloader, that has  access to your class, so it will load it. Despite that its parent (or root) classloaders  have explicit  rule to forbid the loading of that class.

I still recommend to make a wrapper class for this instantiation. You should load that class with your `CustomTestClassLoader`, then you can use `Class.forName()` in that class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I thought the class containing the `test()` method was already loaded by my custom loader since I used the `loader vmarg`. I stepped through the example with the Eclipse debugger to be sure and `Class.forName()` does use an instance of `CustomTestClassLoader` as ClassLoader in this example.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase what I said, so here it goes: I verified that `Class.forName(NAME)` calls `Class.forName(NAME, true, loader)` where `loader` is an instance of my custom classloader. So there is no need to write a wrapper as the classloader is already resolved correctly.

Comment: I recommend the following steps: (1) Run the test in Eclipe in **Debug mode**, set a breakpoint to the beginning of your `loadClass()` method (it can be conditional for the classname, to avoid mass breaks). (2) if it does not help, set a **Class loading breakpoint** (under Run menu) for your classname.

Comment: I just did a new test and noticed the following behaviour:  
if the class requested by `Class.forName` has not yet been loaded, it uses the `loadClass` method of the classloader of the caller.
However, if the class has already been loaded once, it completely ignores the classloader and (this part is just a guess) uses some kind of native code to obtain the class directly from the JVM.

So my question is now, is there any way for me to make `Class.forName` throw a `ClassNotFoundException` even when the class is already loaded?

Comment: Can you debug your code from the `Class.forName()`call, what will be the first `ClassLoader` instance it enters?  I also make some edit, I was imprecise.

Comment: It enters my custom classloader. So now it behaves as expected when the requested class has never been loaded before. I also verified that it completely skips any interaction with the classloader if the class has already been loaded. So I'll just have to make sure that the classes I wish to block are not loaded and run my testcases in a new JVM. Thanks for all the help.